# How to desribe in Hibernate Map<Entity, Enum> field in Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, entity, nhibernate-mapping

I have:

```
public enum Role{
  BOSS, EMPL
}
```

```
public class User{
}
```

```
public class Company{
  Map<User, Role>
}
```

In the output, I want the same table `users` and `company_users` with (`id PRIMARY KEY`, `company (fk)INTEGER`, `user (fk)INTEGER`, `role VARCHAR`).

Answer (score 0):

I apply this code and it work as need!

```
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "workers")
    @Column(name = "role")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Map<User, Role> workers;
```

describe in [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation)